# Can new posts for custom post types be added last in order?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup a custom post type for creating a Staff directory in Wordpress. When I add a new staff member, they automatically appear first in order of all posts, which makes sense for most kinds of post types.

Using [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/) to rearrange the posts is super easy but it also a hassle to do every time, so I was curious to see if anyone knows if there's a way to automatically add new posts last in order?

Using the very basic code in functions.php to add the post type:

```
function create_posttype() {

register_post_type( 'staff',

    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Staff' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Staff' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'staff'),
    )
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many ways to do this, but here is one:

Add an action to alter the ORDER param in your query as shown below.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
});
```

Note that the above query will act on ALL post queries (including in the admin), which is probably not what you want, so you'll have to wrap the `$query->set()` in logic so it only runs on the page(s) you want. For example, to only change the order when working with the staff CPT, use this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( 'staff' == $query->query['post_type'] ) {
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
});
```

Also note that in this action, `$query` is passed by reference, not by assignment, so there is no need to use the `global` keyword nor return anything.

HTH